# Переключатель режимов Node + React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

У меня имеется переключатель, отвечающий за переключение режимов отображения - в одном состоянии выводится форма для записи данных в БД, а в другом - таблица для вывода этих данных на место формы. Когда проводится тестовое переключение на вывод таблицы, все работает исправно, однако при повторном выводе формы эта же форма становится невидимой, хотя все элементы на месте и их функционал сохраняется. Не могу понять, в какую сторону думать, чтобы решить проблемы с отображением формы. Код прилагаю.
Form.js, где выводится форма записи и встроен описанный ранее переключатель:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TableFormSwitcher from "./TableFormSwitcher";
import DataTable from "./DataTable";

function Form() {
  const [displayTable, setDisplayTable] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(`Отображение таблицы: ${displayTable}`);
  }, [displayTable]);

  const handleToggleDisplay = () => {
    setDisplayTable(!displayTable); // Toggle between form and table
    // console.log(displayTable);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <TableFormSwitcher handleToggleDisplay={handleToggleDisplay} displayForm={!displayTable} 
setDisplayTable={setDisplayTable} />
  {displayTable ? (
    <DataTable />
  ) : (
    <form className="contact__form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="input__data">
        <input
          onBlur={title.onBlur}
          value={title.value}
          onChange={title.onChange}
          className="name__input input form__control element-animation"
          type="text"
          placeholder={t("post.title")}
          name="title"
          required
        />
        {title.isDirty && title.isEmpty && <div className="form__error">{t("error.empty")}</div>}
        {title.isDirty && title.minLengthError && (
          <div className="form__error">{t("error.length")}</div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="input__data">
        <input
          onBlur={link.onBlur}
          value={link.value}
          onChange={link.onChange}
          className="link__input input form__control element-animation"
          type="text"
          placeholder={t("post.link")}
          name="link"
          required
        />
        {link.isDirty && link.isEmpty && <div className="form__error">{t("error.empty")}</div>}
        {link.isDirty && link.minLengthError && (
          <div className="form__error">{t("error.length")}</div>
        )}
      </div>

      <DragDropFile onFileChange={handleFileChange} />

      <div className="input__data">
        <textarea
          onBlur={text.onBlur}
          value={text.value}
          onChange={text.onChange}
          className="form__textarea form__control element-animation"
          name="text"
          id=""
          cols="30"
          rows="10"
          placeholder={t("post.text")}
        ></textarea>
        {text.isDirty && text.isEmpty && <div className="form__error">{t("error.empty")}</div>}
        {text.isDirty && text.minLengthError && (
          <div className="form__error">{t("error.length")}</div>
        )}
      </div>

      <div className="input__data">
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="form__btn form__control element-animation"
        >
          {t("post.button")}
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  )}
</div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Код переключателя под названием TableFormSwitcher.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function TableFormSwitcher({ handleToggleDisplay, displayForm }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(displayForm);

  const toggleSwitch = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
    if (typeof handleToggleDisplay === 'function') {
      handleToggleDisplay(); // Call handleToggleDisplay if it's a function
    }
  };

  return (
    <label className="switch">
      <input type="checkbox" checked={isChecked} onChange={toggleSwitch} />
      <span className="slider round"></span>
    </label>
  );
}

export default TableFormSwitcher;
```

Компонент DataTable.js для вывода таблицы с данными из БД:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function DataTable() {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   useEffect(() => {
     fetchData();
   }, []);

   const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get('/api/getDataFromDatabase');
        setData(response.data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching data:', error);
      }
   };

   return (
      <div>
         <h2>Data Table</h2>
         <table>
           <thead>
             <tr>
               <th>Title</th>
               <th>Link</th>
               <th>Photo</th>
               <th>Description</th>
             </tr>
           </thead>
          <tbody>
              {data.map((item, index) => (
                 <tr key={index}>
                   <td>{item.Header}</td>
                   <td>{item.link}</td>
                   <td><img src={item.photo} alt="Photo" style={{ width: '100px', height: 'auto' }} /></td>
                   <td>{item.description}</td>
                 </tr>
               ))}
           </tbody>
        </table>
   </div>
    );
  }

  export default DataTable;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: минимизируй код и оставь только ту часть каторая отвечает за функционал (стили, лишние компоненты и тд). Это реально упрастит понимание и решение проблемы.

Comment: @Armen Подправил немного. Надеюсь, так лучше :)

Comment: *форма становится невидимой, хотя все элементы на месте и их функционал сохраняется* - Можете подробнее рассказать, как это? Не очень понятно, что значит форма есть, но не видна? Вы в консоли видите, что все элементы HTML добавлены, но не отображаются браузером или как?

Comment: @SwaD Все элементы формы есть в консоли, но их просто не видно, будто либо что-то перекрывает, либо они скрыты для просмотра. Если случайно попасть курсором в какое-нибудь изначально имеющееся  в форме текстовое поле, но не заполнить его и убрать курсор, то выводится сообщение об ошибке насчет пустых полей, как и должно быть. Также можно попасть на кнопку загрузки фотографии и она тоже будет отрабатывать, но самой кнопки на экране тоже не будет видно. И все это только после повторного переключения на форму.

Comment: @Dev2502 половина констант и функций отсутсвует в компоненте Form. (сделай так что бы можно было бы хотя бы запустить), да и кстати у тебя по ходу в стилях просто где то стоит opacity:0 а то других причин почему форму не видно но по ней можно тыкать в голову не приходит

Comment: Согласен с @Armen. Проверьте в стилях на экране, нет ли `opacity:0` на самих элементах и элементах родителях

Comment: @SwaD Прикрепил скриншот со стилями и формой

Comment: @Dev2502 начиная с самого вложонного элемента начинай убирать классы до сомого верха, рано или поздно форма отобразится, а там уже поймеш где и какие стили скрывают форму. Но проблема в стилях. я твой код запустил все работает.

Comment: @Armen Ответ лежал на поверхности...  Сыграла моя невнимательность и отсутствие какого-либо нормального опыта во фронтенд разработке. :) Был отдельный файл со всеми стилями, которые применяются к инпутам в форме. Поменял в них одно свойство и все. Остается только один вопрос: считается ли ошибкой наличия свойства opacity: 1 в подобном классе, если так или иначе идет переключение между компонентами с помощью кода? И удовлетворяет ли стандартам React'а использование JQuery на случай, если мы хотим влиять на классы с помощью кода?

Comment: @Dev2502 2. Jquery не вписивается в react, так как он манипулирует напрямую дом деревом, а в реакте виртуалный дом этим занимается. Манипуляция напримую дом дерева нужна в редких случях, и Jquery опят же не нужен. Касательно 1. нужно кодом маниплировать + добавление/удаление классов. Кейс где встретится необходимость скрывать css стилями элемент у меня был один раз и то наверное из за не правильной реализации(там все сложно было).